# Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component when i call useQuery in useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, apollo, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

I am using apollo-graphql in my react project and i am getting error of

> Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Here is my code for this

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

// **************** COMPONENTS ****************
import { GET_MORTGAGE_JOURNEY } from "../../../../Graphql/Journeys/query";

export default function index() {
  const insuranceId = useSelector((state) => state.mortgage.insuranceId);

  // Panels Heading to show on all panels

  useEffect(() => {
    if (insuranceId) {
      getMortgageData(insuranceId);
    }
  }, [insuranceId]);

  function getMortgageData(insuranceId) {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(GET_MORTGAGE_JOURNEY, {
      variables: { id: insuranceId },
    });
    console.log(data);
  }

  return <section className="mortage-journey"></section>;
}
```

Once i run this i get the error, I know that useQuery itself is a hook and i cant call it from inside useEffect, but then what should be the workaround for this as i need insuranceId from my redux state first and send it to the query.

Thanks !

Comment: This is a function `function getMortgageData(insuranceId)` . You cannot call hook inside it. Neither can you call a hook from inside useEffect, since that itself is a callback function. What do you want to achieve.

Comment: initially "insuranceId" variable is null/undefined i want to pick a state from my reducer , set it to "inusranceId" and then call apollo-query

Comment: @TusharShahi so basicallly calling GET_DATA query on mount with "insuranceId" to get my data

Comment: Sure, I think my answer will help you. Have a look and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are breaking the rule of hooks when you call it from any place other than the top level of a `React` component.

`useEffect` takes a callback function, and you are calling your hook from that. It is a problem.

I found this [`skip`](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/api/react/hooks/#skip) option in `useQuery` which helps you call `useQuery` conditionally.

```
    const { loading, error, data } = 
    useQuery(GET_MORTGAGE_JOURNEY, {
      variables: { id: insuranceId },
      skip : (!insuranceId)
    });
```

Any time `insuranceId` changes your callback runs, so it is run after mount once and then on subsequent changes.

Comment: I tried this (for a similar issue), but it gave this error: ```React Hook "useMutation" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks```

Comment: this isn't the right answer and this is not the valid implementation it will through the same error again.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `refetch`. Something like this:

```
const { data, refetch } = useQuery(MY_QUERY);

useEffect(() => {
  refetch();
}, id);
```

You can use `refetch` wherever you like, in `useEffect` or a button click `onclick` handler.

Alternatively, you could use `useLazyQuery` if you don't want it to run the first time:

```
const [goFetch, { data }] = useLazyQuery(MY_QUERY);
```

Now you can use `goFetch` or whatever you want to call it wherever you like.

Your whole example might look like:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { GET_MORTGAGE_JOURNEY } from "../../../../Graphql/Journeys/query";

export default function index() {
  const insuranceId = useSelector((state) => state.mortgage.insuranceId);
  const { loading, error, data, refetch } = useQuery(GET_MORTGAGE_JOURNEY, {
    variables: { id: insuranceId },
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    if (insuranceId) {
      refetch({id: insuranceId});
    }
  }, [insuranceId]);


  return <section className="mortage-journey"></section>;
}
```